# Can libffi be used for Python and Java to communicate?

Tags: java, python, c, libffi

I'm wondering if it is possible for an app to run in Python and call Java methods (and vice versa) through libffi?

Comment: libffi seems a bit too low-level to do this conveniently or safely. There are other options for Java-Python interop, why do you focus on libffi specifically?

Comment: But why C tag, I think you are missing `Python` and `Java` tags.

Comment: I'm still learning about ffi and how it works. The question is not limited to java/python but all combinations of languages with ffi.

Answer (score 1):

In general, things get complicated when you're talking about two managed runtimes (CPython and the JVM, for instance).  libffi only really deals with a subset of the issues here.  I would look more at remote method invocations as a way to integrate code written in different managed runtime environments.